# Get Specific View on Custom ListView

Tags: android

I have a custom list view with simple text and button, this button open a dialog that allow user to delete or save a file, but i want to get the view of the row when i push this button  to perform a delete animation.
How can i get the view of this specific row, inside on a button click listener?
I use a custom array Adapter with Base Adapter!

```
             extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
```

Thanks in advance, i don't know if it's necessary to put here the code, it's so long.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the custom adapter for your list view and add tag to your button that represent the position of your row and after that in your clicklistener you should get the tag and find out that which row has been clicked .

```
  @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         Button yourbtn= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.yourbtnid);

         yourbtn.setTag(position);

         yourbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Button btn = (Button)arg0;

             int position = Integer.parseInt(btn .getTag().toString());

        }

}
```

Comment: i try, but i think i dont use correctly 

in 

        public View getView(int position, View convertView,    ViewGroup parent) {

when i define button parametres, i put:

        holder.btnoption.setTag(position);

 is that  way?, but when i try to get tag, i cant do it by make..

int pos = view.getTag(); 

because int is not an object :S

Comment: you should use int pos = Integer.parseInt(yourbutton.getTag().toString()) .

Comment: ok i understand what you say, my problem is that I  implement View.OnClickListener, so i have my onclick(View arg0), out of the getview ..

thank you for try to help me!!

i found my problem i do one more setTag to the button to pass data structure

can i do, multiple setTag(), and then how to diferrence in getTag()???

setTag(1,data) and them getTag(1) ????

Comment: yes you can do it like what you said . setTag(key, tag) and getTag(key) .

Comment: ok thank you so very much , now i have the position of the button pressed, but i'm in the first problem, now hoe to get the view of this row??? inside the click listener

Comment: use this : View wantedView = listView.getChildAt(position);

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this from the `ListView` by using `ListView.setOnItemSelectedListener()`. The `OnItemSelectedListener` returns the View.

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing your click action inside the Adapter code itself (which I think is not the best way to do it), you can get an instance of the whole strip by calling `getParentView()` as many times as needed, depending on how deep into your parent layout the button is.